# operating system - context switches

Tags: process, operating-system, thread-sleep, context-switch

I have been confused about the issue of context switches between processes, given round robin scheduler of certain time slice (which is what unix/windows both use in a basic sense).

So, suppose we have 200 processes running on a single core machine. If the scheduler is using even 1ms time slice, each process would get its share every 200ms, which is probably not the case (imagine a Java high-frequency app, I would not assume it gets scheduled every 200ms to serve requests). Having said that, what am I missing in the picture?

Furthermore, java and other languages allows to put the running thread to sleep for e.g. 100ms. Am I correct in saying that this does not cause context switch, and if so, how is this achieved?

Comment: If my answer helped, please accept the below answer.

Answer (score 6):

> So, suppose we have 200 processes running on a single core machine. If
>   the scheduler is using even 1ms time slice, each process would get its
>   share every 200ms, which is probably not the case (imagine a Java
>   high-frequency app, I would not assume it gets scheduled every 200ms
>   to serve requests). Having said that, what am I missing in the
>   picture?

No, you aren't missing anything. It's the same case in the case of non-pre-emptive systems. Those having pre-emptive rights(meaning high priority as compared to other processes) can easily swap the less useful process, up to an extent that a high-priority process would run 10 times(say/assume --- actual results are totally depending on the situation and implementation) than the lowest priority process till the former doesn't produce the condition of starvation of the least priority process.

Talking about the processes of similar priority, it totally depends on the Round-Robin Algorithm which you've mentioned, though which process would be picked first is again based on the implementation. And, Windows and Unix have same process scheduling algorithms. Windows and Unix does utilise Round-Robin, but, Linux task scheduler is called Completely Fair Scheduler (CFS).

> Furthermore, java and other languages allows to put the running thread
>   to sleep for e.g. 100ms. Am I correct in saying that this does not
>   cause context switch, and if so, how is this achieved?

Programming languages and libraries implement "sleep" functionality with the aid of the kernel. Without kernel-level support, they'd have to busy-wait, spinning in a tight loop, until the requested sleep duration elapsed. This would wastefully consume the processor.

Talking about the threads which are caused to sleep(`Thread.sleep(long millis)`) generally the following is done in most of the systems :

1. Suspend execution of the process and mark it as not runnable.
2. Set a timer for the given wait time. Systems provide hardware timers that let the kernel register to receive an interrupt at a given point in the future.
3. When the timer hits, mark the process as runnable.

I hope you might be aware of threading models like one to one, many to one, and many to many. So, I am not getting into much detail, jut a reference for yourself.

It might appear to you as if it increases the overhead/complexity. But, that's how threads(user-threads created in JVM) are operated upon. And, then the selection is based upon those memory models which I mentioned above. Check [this Quora question and answers to that one](https://www.quora.com/Linux-Kernel/How-do-programming-languages-implement-sleep-functions), and please go through the best answer given by Robert-Love.

For further reading, I'd suggest you to read from [Scheduling Algorithms explanation on OSDev.org](http://wiki.osdev.org/Scheduling_Algorithms) and [Operating System Concepts book by Galvin, Gagne, Silberschatz](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470128720).